# How can I retrieve the package name of the object using eclipse development JDT API?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I need to get the source package of the any object declared in the class. This object may be declared as a class variable or methods local variable.

I can able to find that for class object variable using IFields API.

For example, if the variable is of type List -> I need the result as java.util.List.

Kindly give your ideas.

Thanks in advance,
Easwar

Comment: You need to be a little bit more clear on what objects you have access to.  Are you working with the AST API, or are you working with the Java model API (ie- IJavaElement)?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The IProject interface extends the IContainer which has several findMember methods. You get all IResource(Java files) and get package name ....

Note: IResource are resources other then Java files also